# Get Anychart network graph selected nodes?

Tags: javascript, anychart

Is there a function for getting selected nodes on network chart?
The selected function available on the documentation are for getting/setting Selected state settings.

What I wanted to do is to fire an event that show all the selected nodes data.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we currently have no functionality to access exact nodes or edges in the Graph chart. 
The [selected() functionality in the documentation](https://api.anychart.com/v8/anychart.core.graph.elements.Node#selected) refers to the appearance settings of a selected node/graph. 
The current, 8.11 version of AnyChart has no functionality to access selected nodes/edges.